# Using a filter in aggregate function in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, filter, aggregate, hana

In PostgreSQL one can use a filter in an aggregate function like for example:

```
SUM(<expression>) FILTER(WHERE <condition>)
```

I want to use such a filter (in fact many different ones) on an aggregate function in SAP HANA.

Unfortunately I was not able to find a possibility to do so, so currently I need to do a lot of joins with subquerys using the "normal" `WHERE` statement to filter the data, which is quite messy.

So my question is: Is there a similar function in SAP HANA to apply a filter on an aggregate function?

Comment: I don't know about Hana but you can use `case when` or `ìif` expressions in `sum` expression you can return 0 where your condition is not met and the actual value when it is met.

Comment: @Eldar true that, feel free to add this as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned in comments by @Eldar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73501170/using-a-filter-in-aggregate-function-in-sap-hana#comment129797369_73501170) you can use `CASE WHEN`, for example:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 END) as CNT_A
SUM(CASE WHEN <condition> AND <condition2> BETWEEN x AND y THEN <expression> ELSE NULL END) as SUM_X
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HAVING clause.

Ex.:

```
SELECT ATTRIBUTE_1
       ,SUM(MEASURE_1)
FROM TABLE_1
GROUP BY ATTRIBUTE_1
HAVING SUM(MEASURE_1) > 0
```

BR,
Gabriel